# Xcode, Custom Class meaning

Tags: xcode

I searched all around stackoverflow and other websites but can not find a very simple thing. I suppose, it could have been answered already, then, could anyone just link the answer?

I am interested in what "custom class" in Xcode is in attributes inspector and how it works, what it actually does. I know very well how to make things work, but I do not have understanding of what I am doing.

To clarify. We can create a UITableViewCell class with, say, name `cellClass`, then we create .xib with the same name. Inside of .xib we drag UITableViewCell on the canvas and select its custom class - the name of the UITableViewCell class created before - in attributes inspector. So, what is this `custom class` in the attributes inspector is not clear for me. The example is very specific though, since we are using `custom class` for other things.

Thanks.

Comment: A custom class is a class you defined by yourself, or? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the possibility to change the class of a predefined object in a `.xib`. If you insert a button to the interface, its class is `NSButton`, this to say that you instanciate an `NSButton`. But, you may have the need to extends `NSButton` into a `MyButton` class with specific added properties, methods, etc. If you want to instantiate it through `.xib` then you just have to drag'n'drop an `NSButton` and change its class to `MyButton` in the Identity inspector tab, Custom class form.

It is not very frequent to use `NSButton` this way, but much more common for some other objects, `NSView` for example (read [Apple docs on subclassing NSView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html))

Comment: It is a particular case of what I am interested in. OK, we can use this feature to customize a button or some other element, but how does it work? What actually happens when we select custom class of the `NSButton` that we put in the .xib? Some kind of linking to the class, created by me, that describes the behavior of the button, I guess, but it is vague, unclear. I thought that some extensive explanations could be found somewhere on this question. Then, such a thing - defining custom class - definitely is not used just for subclassing buttons, it is a special case.

Comment: I think you need to read things about `.xib` files... Objects are serialized in it, so when you declare a custom class, it is an instance of that custom class that is serialized in.

Comment: Why do we need that? To allow for a 'linking' of `.xib` to the class that defines behavior?

Comment: You need that to avoid writing hundred of line of code to build a simple interface (for example). It is also very flexible. It also lets you focus on your model classes.

Answer (score 0):

---

Are you talking about (Extensions, categories).

Please refer to this link:

[Extensions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-succinctly-categories-and-extensions--mobile-22016)

If you having issues in creating new subclases in xcode 7.1 then please click on:

File->New->Cocoa Touch Class-> Classname and select subclass of, it will works and you will be able to assign classes to uiviewcontrollers as well.